# Eclipse editor couldn't be initialized lombok plugin causing problems

Tags: eclipse-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLJva.png)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lombok/launch/PatchFixesHider$Transform
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.endParse(Parser.java:11634)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.CommentRecorderParser.endParse(CommentRecorderParser.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.endParse(SourceElementParser.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12827)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13051)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13008)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.parseCompilationUnit(SourceElementParser.java:1048)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BecomeWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(BecomeWorkingCopyOperation.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:736)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:802)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.becomeWorkingCopy(CompilationUnit.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:481)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.connect(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1284)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4182)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:262)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1479)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2517)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1416)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.lambda$1(AbstractTextEditor.java:3172)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:436)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.lambda$7(WorkbenchWindow.java:2353)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2351)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3189)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3214)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:353)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:736)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.lambda$0(PartServiceImpl.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4992)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:659)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:623)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:786)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:400)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1262)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3197)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3100)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3070)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3061)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:376)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:182)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:285)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$3.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:546)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:802)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1118)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.mouseSelectItem(OpenStrategy.java:437)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4385)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3789)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

I'm unable to open my eclipse editor, lombok plugin is causing the problem. can someone post the solution for this

Comment: You're asking us to assume you've installed Lombok properly. Have you? Walk us through how you did.

Comment: Downloaded jar from https://projectlombok.org/download and executed command in terminal: java -jar lombok.jar. after installation process, i restarted the eclipse.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using *to run Eclipse*? If it's newer than 11, can you try 11?

Answer (score 1):

Add --illegal-access=warn in the eclipse.ini file to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version for the IDE. Install the latest version of the lombok jar and then restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version and lombok version.

Ex: java 17 compatible lombok v1.18.22

Please check java version and lombok version here https://projectlombok.org/changelog